# Substitute current git branch name into git log command

Tags: git

I have a git log command that allows me to see local commits that haven't yet been pushed to the remote repository. It looks like this:

```
ahead = log origin/master..HEAD --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset %d %s %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset %Cblue[%an]%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

This works fine as long as you are on the `master` branch. What I would like is a variable that I could put in the command where `master` is now, so that the `git ahead` alias would run against that branch. Something like the zsh $(git_prompt_info) variable, but that can be used in a gitconfig file as part of an alias definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `@{u}`:

> #### <refname>@{upstream}, e.g. master@{upstream}, @{u}
>
> The suffix @{upstream} to a ref (short form <refname>@{u}) refers to the branch the ref is set to build on top of. A missing ref defaults to the current branch.

So your alias should look like this:

```
ahead = log @{u}..HEAD --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset %d %s %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset %Cblue[%an]%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

But I would recommend changing it to this:

```
ahead = log @{u}...HEAD --graph --decorate --left-right --boundary --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset %d %s %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset %Cblue[%an]%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

This will show both commits in the remote that are missing locally as well as local comits that are missing in the remote.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want. However it produces an error when I run it. I get `error: No upstream configured for branch 'source'`. I guess there something about my repository and/or the `source` branch that isn't entirely kosher.

Comment: ah, ok – this only works if origin/master is actually configured as the upstream branch for master – you do that by running `git push -u origin master`

Comment: `git push -u origin master` even though the branch I'm working on is `source`? I gather setting an upstream branch is something one does once, and always for master?

Comment: No, if you are working on `source`, it’s `git push -u origin source`. And yes – you only need to do this once per branch.